# k6 embbeding on orientable surface of genus 3 with 6 pentagons faces

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I need embbeding K6 on orientable surface of genus 3 . but I was asked to do it with the next stipulation : 5 faces only and all the faces in the embedding will be pentagons .
In my opinion the way to do it is to find planar representation to the  orientable surface of genus 3 ,  and put k6 on him .. but I was tried many ways and could not find such embbeding  .

just to be more clear about what I am talking about , I am attach sketch of k5 embbeding  on torus (genus 1) , when in this time the requirement was to do it with 5 squares faces.

If you have any idea how to draw this embbeding I will be glad for some help 
thank you ![image: k5 embbeding on torus with 5 squares faces] 
Thanks

Comment: Your drawing is not $K_5$, since there is no edge between vertices 3 and 5, but once you have that then you have 5 faces and each is a 4-cycle. What happens when you try to do a similar thing by starting with a hexagon on your new surface?

Comment: We have edge between vertices 3 and 5 , note that all the corners are the  same point .I cant couse we can't embedding k6 on torus .. @jp26

Comment: You cannot have an edge from 3 to 5 through 1, that would be two edges; one edge from 3 to 1 and then one from 1 to 5...
You need to join 3 to 5 through the right hand side of the torus, making the faces 1352 and 1435. Currently you have a face 134152 which is not a 4-cycle...

Comment: In the title you ask for 6 pentagons, but in the question you say 5. By Euler there must be 6 pentagons, so each pentagon must be made of all but one of the vertices. Can you use symmetry?

Comment: I believe that this link contains things which may be useful to you: http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2012-13/2term/ma006b/12Ma6bChp35.pdf

Comment: *6 pentagons , Im sorry .I read it
and I don't understand Their algorithm with pasting polygons.. I tried but it did not work. Apparently I did not find the correct representation of space. (I did it as a surface with four holes so that each pair are basically one hole and the four edges are the same point so that the resulting is a torus with two holes, it's actually a sheet.. But it did not work . Thank you !! @jp26